# React Tutorial: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I decided to learn React and started with the official tutorial. All is good until I get to this state of my code:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1> Comments </h1>
        <CommentList />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentForm">
        Hello, world! I am a comment form;
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: () => {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return {__html: rawMarkup};
  },

  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2> // <--- [[[[[[ ERROR IS HERE ]]]]]]
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHtml={this.rawMarkup} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        <Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>
        <Comment author="Jordan Walke">This is *another* comment yo</Comment>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error in devtools:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

...and the debugger pauses at the marked line (see code). When I mouseover `this` in `{this.props.author}`, I get a preview of the object which has the `props` property and everything...

Comment: I want to add that I was seeing this error recently due to the React dev tools. Just wanted to throw that out there since this is this is the top Google result.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use function declaration ( `render() {}` or `render: function {}`) instead of arrow function `render: () => {}`

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return {__html: rawMarkup};
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHtml={this.rawMarkup} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/22456/)

> An [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target).
>   Arrow functions are always anonymous.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error message:

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

...**but from a different cause**: when `this` is called from within a function, javascript can not reach the variable because **`this` is in an outer scope.** (Note: I was in ES5)

In this case, simply store `this` in another variable, prior to the function (in the scope of your component): **`var that = this;`**

Then you will be able to call **`that.props`** from within the function.

Hope this helps for other people who had that error message.

*Detailed example below:*

```js
render: function() {
  var steps = [];
  var that = this;  // store the reference for later use
  var count = 0;
  this.props.steps.forEach(function(step) {
      steps.push(<Step myFunction={function(){that.props.anotherFunction(count)}}/>);  // here you are
      count += 1;
  });
  return (
    <div>{steps}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late post/answer.

Try to bind your function inside the constructor

example:

```
this.yourfunction = this.yourfunction.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am on ES6 and the arrow function did the trick:    rawMarkup = () => {}

Comment: Arrow functions might cause performance degradation, as this passed prop will be different each render in child component.